# Exit iteration in a loop in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I have a procedure where i use a cursor for looping. I want to exit the loop for one iteration when one of the condition turns fall. My procedure:

```
  CREATE OR REPLACE
 PROCEDURE FIX_DIMS_DOC_PROD_DATA
   AS
Tempcount      VARCHAR(8):=1;

 CURSOR wo_list
 IS
SELECT A,b,c
FROM TAble A,
  Table B,
  Table E
WHERE B.tempid = A.PYID
AND NOT EXISTS
  (SELECT 1
  FROM table C
  WHERE C.tempid1 = B.tempid
  AND C.Doc_Type_Id    = A.Documenttypeid
  )
      AND E.Doc_Id = A.Documenttypeid;
       BEGIN
     FOR DIMS_DOC_REC IN wo_list
     LOOP

 BEGIN

        EXIT  WHEN (DIMS_DOC_REC.A1 IS NOT NULL OR               
     DIMS_DOC_REC.A2 IS NOT NULL);
 DO SOMETHING;
   END;
    END LOOP;
     END;
```

Now when i use the exit command, it directly exits the loop, i only want to exit the iteration.

Please suggest!

Comment: What do you mean exit the "iteration"? Do you mean not do whatever is done in `do something;`?

Comment: Yes ben, whenever my EXIT condition becomes true i dont want to execute that and pick up the next value in the cursor

Comment: `IF(some_condition) THEN CONTINUE END IF;` You can always use `EXIT` too in a `IF` , `EXIT WHEN` is not the only option.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the `continue` key word to skip the rest of the current iteration. More information can be found [here](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/continue_statement.htm#LNPLS01360).